# How do I construct a LINQ (EF) query to project pages of data

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm familiar with most of LINQ's capabilities, but can't seem to figure out how to return a projection of multiple pages of data in a single LINQ query.

Here's the scenario... I'm constructing something of a "mail merge" where each letter contains a table, but the table is limited to, say, 40 rows of information. So if the tabular information for a specific recipient contains 100 rows, I want three projected objects returned; one for the first 40 rows, including the recipient, one for the second 40 rows, again including the same recipient, and one for the final 20 rows with the same recipient.

```
Recipient A: Table Rows: 50
Recipient B: Table Rows: 100
Recipient C: Table Rows: 20

The iteration results that I want are:
{
    Recipient: A,
    Table: (rows 0-39)
},
{
    Recipient: A,
    Table: (rows 40-49)
},
{
    Recipient: B,
    Table: (rows 0-39)
},
{
    Recipient: B,
    Table: (rows 40-79)
},
{
    Recipient: B,
    Table: (rows 80-99)
},
{
    Recipient: C,
    Table: (rows 0-19)
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance or pointers to other sources of information you may be able to provide.

Comment: Can you show us some relevant code? Your homework that failed..

Answer (score 0):

Till some better alternative is suggested, you can use following.

```
var q = db.Recipients;

// this loads all table rows...
// so you should filter q as per 
// needed rowset only
        var listq = q
           .SelectMany(x => 
               x.Table.Select( (y,i)=> new {
                  Key = y.RecipientID + "-" + ((int)i/(int)40),
                  Value = y
               })
           );

        var model = listq.GroupBy(x=>x.Key)
           .Select( x=> new {
               Recipient = x.Select(y=>y.Value.Recipient).First(),
               Table = x.Select(y=>y.Value)
           });
```

1. In first step, we will get all Records with Table Navigation Property populated from database.
2. Next, we will call SelectMany which will flaten the hierarchy but, we will create a new Key which will contain RecipientID and index divided by 40, so first Recipient is 1, and index  is 1, so Key will be 1-0, so on for 41'st Index, Key will be 1-1.
3. We will then group by newly created Key,
4. Then we will Select Recipient and Table by select First Recipient and Enumerating rest in Table.

Complete Working Sample is here..

```
    public class Recipient
    {
        public Recipient()
        {
            Table = new List<Table>();
        }
        public long RecipientID { get; set; }
        public List<Table> Table { get; set; }
    }

    public class Table
    {
        public long TableID { get; set; }
        public long RecipientID { get; set; }
        public Recipient Recipient { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Add(List<Recipient> list, long index, int p2)
    {
        Recipient r = new Recipient
        {
            RecipientID = index
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < p2; i++)
        {
            Table t = new Table
            {
                TableID = i,
                Recipient = r,
                RecipientID = r.RecipientID
            };
            r.Table.Add(t);
        }
        list.Add(r);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Recipient> list = new List<Recipient>();

        Add(list, 1, 80);
        Add(list, 2, 15);
        Add(list, 3, 99);

        var listq = list
           .SelectMany(x => 
               x.Table.Select( (y,i)=> new {
                  Key = y.RecipientID + "-" + ((int)i/(int)40),
                  Value = y
               })
           );

        var model = listq.GroupBy(x=>x.Key)
           .Select( x=> new {
               Recipient = x.Select(y=>y.Value.Recipient).First(),
               Table = x.Select(y=>y.Value)
           });


        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",item.Recipient.RecipientID,item.Table.Count());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```